# Why is it that for a linear map $T\in L(V,W)$, dim range $T$ = dim range $T'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

I'm able to follow the proof:

dim range $T'$

= dim$W'$ - dim null $T'$

= dim $W$ - dim(range $T$)$^0$

= dim range $T$

However, I'm looking for a better explanation on *why* they are equivalent. I think my problem stems from still having an unsatisfying understanding of how exactly $T$ and $T'$ are related or affect each other. A better way to phrase my question might be "Do the two ranges happen to have an equal number of dimensions, or is there some underlying property that is causing this?"

Here, I'm using $T'$ to denote the dual map of $T$, and the notation $U^0$ to denote the annihalator of $U$.

Comment: I think you have used the underlying property, namely that $\textrm{im}(T)^\perp  = \ker T'$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nearly all the concepts you're using there haha

Comment: Oh, ok. Actually, I cannot understand myself the $0$ exponent on the third line of reasoning. $\ker$ is the same as kernel, or null space. $\textrm{im}$ is the image space, same as the range.I thought that the zero meant "orthogonal space", which is represented by $\perp$. I have written the same thing as you, but in truth this is the most intricate reason why they are equivalent. In infinite dimensions the above will not hold true, for example, hence this fact is behind the equivalence.

Comment: Oh sorry. In the book I am using (Linear Algebra Done Right), the 0 exponent of a set refers to that set's annihalator, where the annihalator is defined as: given a set $U\subset V$, $U^0=\{\varphi \in V': \varphi (u)=0$ for all $u \in U  \}$.

Comment: Ok, hang on. $T'$ is the transpose of $T$, right? (or the adjoint of $T$).

Comment: T' is the dual of T. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question to include these details.

Comment: The dual is the same as  the adjoint, which in matrix representation is the same as the transpose. So the statement I made about infinite dimensional spaces still holds.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Be careful. In order for $\operatorname{mat}(T')$ to equal $\operatorname{mat}(T)^T$ you have to use dual bases.

Comment: @amd In finite dimensions doesn't everything work out, though? I mean, the statement made by OP is correct for finite dimensions, and the reason behind that is this fact.

Comment: Absolutely. However, if you mostly work in $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard bases, it’s easy to overlook the fine point that you need to use dual bases in order to represent $\phi(u)$ as a matrix multiplication in the first place. For the matrix of the adjoint operator to be the transpose of the operator’s matrix requires the use of dual bases in both dual spaces involved.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the adjoint operator is that you can either first go from $V$ to $W$ via $T$ and then apply an element of $W'$ to the result, or you can instead go from $W'$ to $V'$ via $T'$ and then apply that to an element of $V$. Both give the same result.

As астон says in his comments, the underlying reason for the equality of the range dimensions is the connection between the images and kernels of the adjoint operators: $$\begin{align}(\operatorname{im}T)^0&=\ker(T')\\\operatorname{im}(T')&=(\ker T)^0.\end{align}$$ These equalities follow directly from the definition of the adjoint $$(T'\mathbf\beta)[\mathbf v]=\mathbf\beta[T\mathbf v].\tag{1}$$
If we express the above definition of adjoint in matrix form, the connections become fairly obvious. Recall that if we choose dual bases for $V$ and $V'$, we can represent elements of $V'$ as row vectors for which $\mathbf\alpha[\mathbf v]$ becomes the matrix product $$\pmatrix{\alpha_1&\cdots&\alpha_n}\pmatrix{v_1\\\vdots\\v_n}.$$ Applying a transformation to an element of a dual space corresponds to *right*-multiplying a row vector by a matrix. Using dual bases for $W$ and $W'$ as well, the expression $\mathbf\beta[T\mathbf v]$ then becomes the matrix product $$\pmatrix{\beta_1&\cdots&\beta_m}\pmatrix{t_{11}&\cdots&t_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\t_{m1}&\cdots&t_{mn}}\pmatrix{v_1\\\vdots\\v_n}$$ and equation (1) is just a restatement of the associative law for matrix multiplication. In this representation, the matrices of $T$ and $T'$ are identical. We can choose bases for $V$ and $W$ (and their dual bases for $V'$ and $W'$) in which the matrix of $T$ has a particularly simple form*: $$\pmatrix{\beta_1&\cdots&\beta_m}\left(\begin{array}{c|c}I_r&0\\\hline0&0\end{array}\right)\pmatrix{v_1\\\vdots\\v_n}$$ where $r=\operatorname{rank}T$. It should be obvious from this product that $\dim\operatorname{im}T=\dim\operatorname{im}T'=r$. The equalities between kernels and annihilators of the adjoint operators can also be seen by inspection of this product.

---

* Choose a basis $\mathbf{v}_{r+1},\dots,\mathbf{v}_n$ for $\ker T$ and extend it to a basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_n$ of $V$. Let $\mathbf{w}_i=T\mathbf{v}_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r$ and extend to a basis $\mathbf{w}_1,\dots,\mathbf{w}_m$ of $W$.